# how to redirect user to various screen based on remote notification type

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate, remote-notifications

I am receiving remote notification's in my application. Following code is written in `AppDelegate` file which called when i receive notification.

get notification when app is in background

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Notification Recieved")

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1

    //process notification

    for (key,val) in userInfo{

        let nkey = key as! String

        if nkey == "notificationType"{
            let notificationType = val as! String

            handleNotificationScreen(type: notificationType)
        }
    }
}
```

Above function get called when app is in background and user clicks on notification in that function `userInfo` is a payload which contains info of notification. In userInfo I am passing `notificationType` from server which contains various values like `TASK`,`KRA` etc

Now based on these `notificationType` values I want to launch different screens.
If notificationType is `TASK`  Then launch Task Screen when user clicks on notification.

I have a `TabBarController` which have multiple `viewControllers`

```
viewControllers = [taskController,messageController,notificationConroller,userProfileNavigationController,empCorner,perfomranceVC]
```

Now what should I do to launch screen in my `handleNotificationScreen(type: notificationType)` function.

```
func handleNotificationScreen(type: String){

        switch type {
        case "KRA":
            print("anc")
        case "TASK":
            print("task")
        case "EMPMONTH":
            print("empMonth")
        default:
            print("none")
        }
    }
```

Thank you guys for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the reference of your `TabBarController` and inside `handleNotificationScreen` , if you want to get `TabBarControllers` inside in `Appdelegate`, Declare property optional like this.

```
var tabbarController: UITabBarController?
```

inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function call this

tabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController

Now can use **tabbarController** to call your specific controller in your desired function.

```
func handleNotificationScreen(type: String){

    switch type {
    case "KRA":
        print("anc")
    case "TASK":
        print("task")
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 //it will open taskbarcontroler
    case "EMPMONTH":
        print("empMonth")
    default:
        print("none")
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i redirect to a controllers which is under `MoreController` ?

Comment: I have 7 controllers from which 4 visible on the tab bar and other 3 comes under MoreController which is automatically generated by swift. so how do i move to those controllers ? @Shauket

Comment: right now how others controller are appearing on screen ?

Comment: [screen](https://ibb.co/caG9ro) check this screen shot where there is a tabController at bottom which contains viewControllers and there is MoreController as a last tab which contains two other viewControllers . @Shauket

Comment: I want to go to view controllers which comes under MoreControllers.

Comment: for more view controller are you using navigation controller ?

Comment: I have solved a problem to move controllers under more controller `customTabController?.selectedViewController = customTabController?.viewControllers![4]` this will do it.